# Angular Unit Testing - stub complex object

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-test

In my unit tests, I have to create stubs that have a large number of properties.

So I would have an interface like this:

```
interface Person {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number
  ...
}
```

Then I will have to create an object that implements this interface and pass some values to each property.
Doesn't Jasmine have a function that receives an interface and returns an object with default values?

In the example above, I would get:

```
const stub: Person = createStubObj<Person>();
stub.id // ""
stub.name // ""
stub.getAge // 0
```

I did some research but didn't found anything useful.

**createSpyObj** doesn't seem to help me because I don't have any functions that I want to spy on. The object only has properties.

This case can happen when an HTTP request returns a complex object (many properties, nested properties). I'm wondering how can I mock that object in that case, without needing to specify a value for each property.

Something similar to what this library is doing: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-auto-mock#usage

I'm wondering if this can be achieved in Jasmine as well or if there is a better approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to create specific mock objects that can be injected into the component under test using the TestBed provider registration:

```
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        providers: [
            TestComponent,
            { provide: RealInterfaceType, useValue: new MockObjectType() }
        ]
    });
```

You can then define the appropriate property values in the mock object. Equally you can use the mock object to be the response from a dependent service by setting up a spy:

```
    serviceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('SomeService', ['someFunction']);
    serviceSpy.someFunction.and.returnValue(new MockObjectType());
```

For http calls, I generally test them as follows...

```
let injector: TestBed;
let service: TestService;
let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
const expectedResponse: TestObject = new TestObject();

beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
        providers: [
            TestService
    });
    injector = getTestBed();
    service = injector.get(TestService);
    httpMock = injector.get(HttpTestingController);
});

afterEach(() => {
    httpMock.verify();
});

describe('someFunction', () => {
    it('should return an Observable<UserAuthResponse>', () => {
        service.someFunction().subscribe(response => {
            expect(response).toBe(expectedResponse);
        });
        const req = httpMock.expectOne('http://the-expected-url');
        expect(req.request.method).toBe('GET');

        // return the static expected value
        req.flush(expectedResponse);
    });
});
```

This is merely testing the expecting http method and URL though.

Comment: Thank you for your response!
What about the case where you need to mock the response from an HTTP service that is quite complex (has multiple properties, nested properties ...) ? Do you define each property with a default value?  something similar like what this library is doing: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-auto-mock#usage but I'm wondering if this can be achieved in Jasmine as well or if there is another approach?

Comment: Updated my previous answer with the code I use for testing http services.  Not sure if there is an easier way though.

Comment: That auto-mocking library looks useful - I will probably try that next time I write some angular code.